# How do you deal with CA certificates in chrome and firefox programmatically in selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, ssl, firefox, ca

I have a selenium hub setup with chrome and firefox as nodes using [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) version 4.

I want to test an app with a certificate generated from a test CA system.

How can I import the CA root certificate in chrome and firefox programmatically ?

I can easily import the CA certificate in the container itself by mounting `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` with the test CA certificate in it but chrome and firefox use their own certificates db.

I use `capybara` to set the browsers capabilities for my tests.

I do not want to use any settings that accept insecure certificates as correct certificates installation is part of my tests.